# Trying to complete exercise 1, Chapter 8, section 8.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, railstutorial.org

This is my first post here so hopefully I have followed the guide but if there is a better way to post, feel free to point me in the right direction - I learn fast.

I am new to rails and working through the Hartl Rails Tutorial. I searched google and here for the solution but can't seem to locate an answer to why the tests fail on click_button "Sign in".

I also went through the rails casts video [Railscasts #270 Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)

What am I missing so I can get these tests to pass? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All the test pass if i use the form_for but fail when I use form_tag in .sessions/new.html.erb. The Sign_in page still renders correctly but once I try to sign in, the web page shows an error on:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
```

Here is the exercise that I am trying to accomplish - Chapter 8, section 8.5, exercise 1:

> 8.5 Exercises
>
> 1. Refactor the signin form to use form_tag in place of form_for. Make
>      sure the test suite still passes. Hint: See the RailsCast on
>      authentication in Rails 3.1, and note in particular the change in
>      the structure of the params hash.

.sessions/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
    <h1>Sign in</h1>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">

    <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field :email, params[:email] %>

    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>

    <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>




    <!--
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    -->


    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the output of rspec spec/

```
> Failures:

  1) Authentication signin with invalid information
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Sign in" }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin with invalid information
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Sign in" }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Authentication signin with invalid information after visiting another page
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Sign in" }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Authentication signin with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Authentication signin with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Authentication signin with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Authentication signin with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top    (required)>'
    .....
```

./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do
 before { visit signin_path }

it { should have_content('Sign in') }
it { should have_title('Sign in') }
end

#Testing for sign in failure
describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Sign in" }

  it { should have_title('Sign in') }

  # This uses Capabara have_selector method
  # dot means "class" in CSS testing for div tag with classes "alert"
  # and "alert-error" and the error message contains "invalid"

  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

    describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
    end
    end

# Testing for sign success
describe "with valid information" do
    # This is using FactoryGirl gem
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before do
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
  # Uses Capybara's have_link method - takes arguments as text 
  # of the link and optional :href
  it { should have_title(user.name) }
  it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
  it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
  end
  end
end
end
```

./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.

        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else

        # Flash [:error] comes from bootstap CSS
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'

        # This line activates the link signin to show the page view      new.html.erb
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
end

 end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSPEC erros on Chapter 9 of Ruby Tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253570/rspec-erros-on-chapter-9-of-ruby-tutorial)

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question was a quite respectable first post. You might want to take at the edit to see some of the markup issues. The markup editor icons '' and {} take a while to get used to. You generally want to paste your test, select what you've pasted and then click the appropriate icon (quote or code).

Comment: Thanks @Peter for the helpful hint.

I did look at the post but since I am not in Ch 9 yet, somethings are not covered so things covered thru Ch 8 should work. 

I did try:
`code`
    def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
`code`
except for the redirect_back_or user and that did not work. It still gave me errors in the same place

Comment: Did you look at the answer in the question I referenced? Your use of `params[:session]` is the problem, as the `params` structure changed. `params[:session]` is `nil`.  You need to use `params[:email]` as the answer indicated. Since the exercises are optional, it's understandable that the other person didn't hit this problem until he started using `form_tag`.

Comment: See also the "show notes" from http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1 where they include a `session_controller.rb` listing which includes the `params[:email]` reference.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

      <%= label_tag :email %>
      <%= text_field_tag :email %>

      <%= label_tag :password %>
      <%= password_field_tag :password %>

      <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

sessions_controller.erb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Please tell me if it works for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the exercise is mentioned that the structure of the params hash is changed. You need to edit this in the controller like following (this works in my case). It does not work currently because the params aren't accessible.

User.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase) and authenticate(params[:password]) are modified. If somebody can elaborate why this is feel free to do so.

An extract of my code you can find here:

```
 def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      # Sign in the user and redirect to user show page
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```